# Excluding all records with associated values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There are multiple payment tags in the `cnsmr_pymnt_tag` table associated with every consumer in the `cnsmr` table.

If any of the consumer's payments have one of the tag ID's listed below (416,417,2823, etc.) then I don't want the the `cnsmr_idntfr_id` in the results.

My code below works if none of the consumer's payments have one of the tag_IDs, but if the consumer has a mixture of Tag_ID codes that are on and off my list, then I get incorrect results and the consumer number ends up in my results.

I understand it's doing exactly what I'm telling to but how do I change it so that the consumer number isn't in the results if it's associated with any of the tag_ID values?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 cnsmr.cnsmr_idntfr_agncy_id 
FROM        
 cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl 
 INNER JOIN
 cnsmr_pymnt_tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id = cnsmr_pymnt_tag.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id 
 INNER JOIN
 tag ON cnsmr_pymnt_tag.tag_id = tag.tag_id 
 INNER JOIN
 cnsmr ON cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl.cnsmr_id = cnsmr.cnsmr_id
WHERE  
 cnsmr_pymnt_tag.TAG_ID NOT IN  
 (        416  -- VOLUNTARY
         ,417  -- VOLUNTARY
         ,2823 -- VOLUNTARY SPEED PAY
         ,583 -- SPEED PAY
         ,1130  -- VOLUNTARY TVOLCC
         ,581 -- VOLUNTARY LBXVOL TAG
 )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you are looking for a list of consumer IDs that have absolutely no payment journals with a tag of 416, 417, 581, 583, 1130, 2823. If that is correct, what you probably want is just a simple WHERE NOT EXISTS that will invalidate any consumer ids that have any of those tags on any payment journals

```
SELECT DISTINCT
C.cnsmr_idntfr_agncy_id
FROM cnsmr AS M
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM tag AS T
        JOIN cnsmr_pymnt_tag AS CPT
            ON T.tag_id = CPT.tag_id
        JOIN cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl AS CPJ
            ON CPT.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id = CPJ.cnsmr_pymnt_jrnl_id
        JOIN cnsmr AS C
            ON CPJ.cnsmr_id = C.cnsmr_id
    WHERE T.tag_id IN (416,417,581,583,1130,2823)
        AND C.cnsmr_id = M.cnsmr_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code like this

```
WHERE  
 cnsmr_pymnt_tag.TAG_ID NOT IN  
 (        416  -- VOLUNTARY
  )
and 
 cnsmr_pymnt_tag.TAG_ID NOT IN  (471)
```

......and so on

Or,you also can try something like below..

```
;with cte(tag)
as 
 (        416  -- VOLUNTARY
         ,417  -- VOLUNTARY
         ,2823 -- VOLUNTARY SPEED PAY
         ,583 -- SPEED PAY
         ,1130  -- VOLUNTARY TVOLCC
         ,581 -- VOLUNTARY LBXVOL TAG
 )
 (your whole query as in question) wq
join
cte c
on c.tag<>wq.tag
```